# norm of $T$ induced by the 1-norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

How to prove this:

If $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\|T\|= \sup_{i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}} \|Te_i\|_1$, for $\|T\|$ the operator norm of $T$ induced by the $1$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so that $x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i$ for $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and suppose that $x$ is a unit vector for the $1$-norm, i.e., $1 = \|x\|_1 := \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$. Then
$$
 \|Tx\|_1 = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i T e_i\right\|_1 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \|Te_i\|_1 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \sup_i\|T e_i\|_1 = \sup_i \|T e_i\|_1,
$$
so that
$$
 \|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|_1 = 1} \|Tx\|_1 \leq \sup_i \|T e_i\|_1.
$$
On the other hand, since each $e_i$ is a unit vector for the $1$-norm, for each $i$,
$$
 \|T e_i\|_1 \leq \sup_{\|x\|_1=1} \|Tx\|_1 = \|T\|,
$$
and hence
$$
 \sup_i \|Te_i\|_1 \leq \|T\|.
$$

Comment: Can you explain why $$
 \|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|_1 = 1} \|Tx\|_1 \leq \sup_i \|T e_i\|. 
$$ and I think it should be $\sup_i \|T e_i\|_1$. You lost many footnotes "1".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the subscripts. The point is that for any $x$ with $\|x\|_1 = 1$, $\|Tx\|_1 \leq \sup_i \|T e_i\|_1$, so that  $\sup_i \|T e_i\|_1$ is an upper bound for $\{\|Tx\|_1 \mid \|x\|_1 = 1\}$. Since $\|T\|$, by definition, is precisely the least upper bound of $\{\|Tx\|_1 \mid \|x\|_1 = 1\}$, it is less than or equal to any upper bound, and in particular, less than or equal to the upper bound $\sup_i \|T e_i\|_1$.

Comment: Why $||T||$ is the least upper bound of {$||Tx||_1\;\;||x||_1=1$}?

Comment: By definition of the operator norm on $B(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$? Note that
$ \|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|_1=1} \|Tx\|_1 = \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|_1}{\|x\|_1}$, since any non-zero vector can be normalised to a unit vector.

 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm

Comment: and why$$
 \|T e_i\|_1 \leq \sup_{\|x\|_1=1} \|Tx\|_1 = \|T\|,
$$? I am really a little bit freaked out...

Comment: Because each of the $e_i$, your standard ordered basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, is, in particular, a unit vector for $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that $\|Te_i\|_1 \in \{\|Tx\|_1 \mid \|x\|_1 = 1\}$, the set whose supremum is precisely $\|T\|$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7956/discussion-between-ian-and-branimir-cacic)

Comment: But how about if $x$ is not a unit vector for the 1-norm?

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you!
Ian: That's fine, because $$\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|_1}{\|x\|_1} = \sup_{x \neq 0} \left\| T\left( \frac{1}{\|x\|_1} x\right)\right\| = \sup_{\|y\|_1 = 1} \|Ty\|_1.$$

Comment: By definition, I know $||T||=sup_{||x||=1}||Tx||$ but is that $||T||=sup_{||x||_1=1}||Tx||_1$?

Comment: If you're working with $\mathbb{R}^n$ together with the $1$-norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ in this problem, then that's the only norm on vectors in play; you're computing the operator norm for (continuous) linear transformations $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1) \to (\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$, aren't you?