# how to get the contractive map modulus of a matrix

Tags: markov-chains, lipschitz-functions

I'm studying the basic theory of fixed-point iteration.
The proof of convergence involves the theory of contractive mapping:

$$|f(t,y2) − f(t,y1)| ≤ K |y2 −y1|$$

I'm wondering how can I specify the Lipschitz constant $K$, if there exist the value $K$, can I get the range of it?

In my application, function $f$ is a matrix.
I have the iteration

$$x = Tx$$

$T$ is a matrix. I know that if $T$ is a Markov Transition matrix, it must converge. What if $T$ is a normal matrix? How can I get the Lipschitz constant of it?

Answer (score 0):

The Lipschitz constant of the linear transformation $y=Tx$ is the *induced matrix norm*
$$\|T\| = \sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$$
Indeed, $\|Tx-Ty\| = \|T(x-y)\| \le \|T\|\|x-y\|$ by construction.

The value of $\|T\|$ depends on the vector norm used above. For the Euclidean norm $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum |x_i|^2}$ it is equal to the largest singular value of $T$, which is also $\max \sqrt{|\lambda_j|}$ where $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $T^*T$. This is hard to compute explicitly; one has to use numerics.

But for the $1$-norm the induced matrix norm [is easy to compute](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/333255): sum the absolute values of the entries in each column, and take the maximum of these sums.   For the $\infty$-norm, the same but for rows instead of columns.